# How to prevent Cartopy automatically rotating tick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am using Python 3.8.2, Matplotlib 3.2.1 and Cartopy 0.18.0.

When I create a map in Cartopy, it sometimes rotates tick labels even when I don't ask it to.  This seems to happen *iff* latitude ticks line up exactly with the horizontal axis.  For example:

```
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Set up plot
lats = (-0.01, 50.01)
lons = (-0.01, 50.01)
meridians = range(0, 51, 10)
parallels = range(0, 51, 10)
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=proj)

# Lat/lon labels
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0)
ax.set_xticks(meridians)
ax.set_yticks(parallels)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# Set domain
ax.set_extent(tuple(lons + lats), crs=proj)

# Show
plt.show()
```

This produces the plot below.  As you can see, some of the latitude ticklabels are rotated.  How do I prevent this behaviour?

[image: Cartopy plot with some ticklabels rotated]

Comment: It's not a very helpful answer, but one thing I noticed is that the tick label rotation does not happen if I use Jupyter Lab (and the same versions of Python, matplotlib and cartopy). It does happen if the figure is produced in a standalone script.